# Eclipse/Maven import problems (with project lombok dependency)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jpa, lombok

I've got a maven project (`myproject-data`) containing a set of JPA Entity classes, imported as dependency in several other (Spring Boot) projects.

Currently I would like to refactor my entity classes by taking advantage of project lombok and eliminate getters/setters from my entities code.

I added lombok's dependency to my pom.xml, and added the `@Data` annotation to one of my entities' class. After doing this, if I build the project with maven from the command line (`mvn package`) I got a BUILD SUCCESS. On the other hand, it seems that the imported dependency is not visible in Eclipse (I'm using Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.7.2.RELEASE): Soure -> Organize imports has no effect, and if I add the `import` statements manually, I got "import cannot be resolved errors" as shown in the code below.

Below is my pom file (the only change with respect to the previous working version is lombok's dependency addition) and under it a snippet of my Entity class source code.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>eu.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject-data</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <name>MyProject Data Model</name>
    <description>This produced a shared jar containing JPA Entity definitions for MyProject data model</description>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- the following dependency is the only addition to the pom.xml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

My entity class (`Detection.java`):

```
.
.
.
import lombok.Data; 
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
/* "The import lombok cannot be resolved " */
.
.
.   
@Data /* "Data cannot be resolved to a type" */
@Entity
public class Detection {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Can you see the jar under "Maven Dependencies"?

Comment: no, i can't see any lombok related jar

Comment: Try running ```Maven install```.

Comment: thanks to your first comment, I tried to just perform a "Maven -> Update" in eclipse and now the jar has appeared. Many thanks!